# How to show labels in custom range on AxisX in MSchart?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, graph, mschart

Is it possible to show labels on AxisX only for column with any values? I have long range X values, but most of them are empty (without Y values).

There's no need to show all X labels, but only under columns with Y values > 0.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
    foreach (DataPoint p in series.Points)
        if (Math.Abs(p.YValues[0]) < 0.00000001)
            p.AxisLabel = String.Empty;
```